# Using Sysdeo Tomcat Launcher Plugin with Tomcat 6 and Apache Ivy

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ivy, launcher

I am using Ivy to manage dependencies, but when I launch Tomcat some problems ocurr. The libraries aren't loading. I think the Sysdeo Laucher doesn't found the Ivy's classpath container. I don't deploy my applications into Tomcat's webapps, I use context files to adress to my eclipse workspace. How can I solve this? I tried DevLoader to resolve this, but it doesn't work.